# React JS yup, react-bootstrap libraries not working in local PC

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, yup, react-forms

I'm working on **react-form-hook** with **yup** validation. All dependencies are installed well and updated in package.json file but validations are not working.

All those **yup** validations are well in codesandbox.io with the same code. And I've added a nav bar with **react-bootstrap** and that too is not working.

Below are the dependencies installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@hookform/error-message": "0.0.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.10.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "rsuite": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
```

Below is the import section

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as Yup from "yup";
```

I get no errors at all.

Comment: You use `Yup` in capital use like this `import * as yup from 'yup'`

Comment: Thanks, But that didn't help. yup is still not working.

Comment: can you import `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'` in App.scss?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Kantivekariya i'm just using css, and i've imported 'react-bootstrap' in specific file